# Build VPNC using Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-ndk, linux-kernel

i have an open source for VPNC linux based on C++ language. Download link is: http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~massar/vpnc/ (i use vpnc-0.5.3.tar.gz).

So, i want to build all source code to .so library using android ndk and cygwin on windows.

First, when i compile the source code on cygwin i have the error: "grcypt.h no such file or directory" and i solved it by paste gcrypt.h file to jni folder on android project. But i enter the problem below:

```
$ /cygdrive/C/Working/Ke/Android/android-ndk-r8b/ndk-build
SharedLibrary  : libvpnc.so
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/vpnc/vpnc.o: In function `lifetime_ike_process':
C:\Working\Ke\Projects\Eclipse\AndroidVpnc/jni/vpnc.c:1171: undefined reference to `opt_debug'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/vpnc/vpnc.o: In function `lifetime_ipsec_process':
C:\Working\Ke\Projects\Eclipse\AndroidVpnc/jni/vpnc.c:1189: undefined reference to `opt_debug'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/vpnc/vpnc.o: In function `make_socket':
C:\Working\Ke\Projects\Eclipse\AndroidVpnc/jni/vpnc.c:242: undefined reference to `error'
C:\Working\Ke\Projects\Eclipse\AndroidVpnc/jni/vpnc.c:219: undefined reference to `error'
C:\Working\Ke\Projects\Eclipse\AndroidVpnc/jni/vpnc.c:231: undefined reference to `error'
C:\Working\Ke\Projects\Eclipse\AndroidVpnc/jni/vpnc.c:238: undefined reference to `error'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/vpnc/vpnc.o: In function `isakmp_crypt':
C:\Working\Ke\Projects\Eclipse\AndroidVpnc/jni/vpnc.c:531: undefined reference to `xallocc'
C:\Working\Ke\Projects\Eclipse\AndroidVpnc/jni/vpnc.c:532: undefined reference to `gcry_cipher_open'
C:\Working\Ke\Projects\Eclipse\AndroidVpnc/jni/vpnc.c:533: undefined reference to `gcry_cipher_setkey'
```

Please give me the solution for this problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this for an app that will only work with rooted devices? Just checking... because it doesn't sound very useful to have a vpnc .so that links with a non-root Java process on Android.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the libraries that contains opt_debug, error, xalloc, gcry_cipher_open and gcry_cipher_setkey as well.